# android - Вызов метода из другого класса (файла)

Tags: java, android

Нужно собрать 4 адаптера для `ListView` в одном методе одного класса и вернуть `ArrayList` с ними в класс игры. Оба файла разные, пришлось их разделить, так как в моей среде разработки (AIDE) ограничения на количество кода. Делаю так:

**ListBuilder.java**

```
public class ListBuilder extends Activity {
String[] from = {"todo", "inspiration", "popularity", "money", "guitar", "vocals", "charisma"};
int[] to = {R.id.todo, R.id.inspiration, R.id.popularity, R.id.money, R.id.guitar, R.id.vocals, R.id.charisma};
public ArrayList<SimpleAdapter> lv_builder(){

    //заполняем массивы из ресурсов
    String[] inspiration_todo = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.inspiration_todo);
    String[] inspiration_inspiration = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.inspiration_inspiration);
    String[] inspiration_money = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.inspiration_money);
    String[] inspiration_charisma = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.inspiration_charisma);
    String[] skills_todo = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.skills_todo);
    String[] skills_inspiration = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.skills_inspiration);
    String[] skills_money = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.skills_money);
    String[] skills_guitar = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.skills_guitar);
    String[] skills_vocals = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.skills_vocals);
    String[] skills_charisma = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.skills_charisma);
    String[] popular_todo = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.popular_todo);
    String[] popular_inspiration = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.popular_inspiration);
    String[] popular_money = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.popular_money);
    String[] popular_popular = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.popular_popular);
    String[] performances_todo = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.performances_todo);
    String[] performances_inspiration = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.performances_inspiration);
    String[] performances_popular = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.performances_popular);

    //инициализация списочных массивов и коллекций
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al_inspiration = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al_skills = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al_popularity = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al_performances = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> hm_inspiration;
    HashMap<String, String> hm_skills;
    HashMap<String, String> hm_popularity;
    HashMap<String, String> hm_performances;

    //заполняем списочные массивы 
    //коллекциями из массивов
    for (int inspiration_for = 0; inspiration_for < inspiration_todo.length; inspiration_for++) {
        hm_inspiration = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm_inspiration.put("todo", inspiration_todo[inspiration_for]);
        hm_inspiration.put("inspiration", inspiration_inspiration[inspiration_for]);
        hm_inspiration.put("popularity", "0");
        hm_inspiration.put("money", inspiration_money[inspiration_for]);
        hm_inspiration.put("guitar", "0");
        hm_inspiration.put("vocals", "0");
        hm_inspiration.put("charisma", inspiration_charisma[inspiration_for]);
        al_inspiration.add(hm_inspiration); }
    for (int skills_for = 0; skills_for < skills_todo.length; skills_for++) {
        hm_skills = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm_skills.put("todo", skills_todo[skills_for]);
        hm_skills.put("inspiration", skills_inspiration[skills_for]);
        hm_skills.put("popularity", "0");
        hm_skills.put("money", skills_money[skills_for]);
        hm_skills.put("guitar", skills_guitar[skills_for]);
        hm_skills.put("vocals", skills_vocals[skills_for]);
        hm_skills.put("charisma", skills_charisma[skills_for]);
        al_skills.add(hm_skills); }
    for (int popularity_for = 0; popularity_for < popular_todo.length; popularity_for++){
        hm_popularity = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm_popularity.put("todo", popular_todo[popularity_for]);
        hm_popularity.put("inspiration", popular_inspiration[popularity_for]);
        hm_popularity.put("popularity", popular_popular[popularity_for]);
hm_popularity.put("money", popular_money[popularity_for]);
        hm_popularity.put("guitar", "0");
        hm_popularity.put("vocals", "0");
        hm_popularity.put("charisma", "0");
        al_popularity.add(hm_popularity); }
    for (int performances_for = 0; performances_for < performances_todo.length; performances_for++){
        hm_performances = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm_performances.put("todo", performances_todo[performances_for]);
        hm_performances.put("inspiration", performances_inspiration[performances_for]);
        hm_performances.put("popularity", performances_popular[performances_for]);
        hm_performances.put("money", "0");
        hm_performances.put("guitar", "0");
        hm_performances.put("vocals", "0");
        hm_performances.put("charisma", "0");
        al_performances.add(hm_performances); }

    //из полученных списочных массивов создаем адаптеры
    Game game = new Game();
    SimpleAdapter sa_inspiration = new CustomAdapter(game, al_inspiration, R.layout.item, from, to);
    SimpleAdapter sa_skills = new CustomAdapter(game, al_skills, R.layout.item, from, to);
    SimpleAdapter sa_popularity = new CustomAdapter(game, al_popularity, R.layout.item, from, to);
    SimpleAdapter sa_performances = new CustomAdapter(game, al_performances, R.layout.item, from, to);

    //заполняем ArrayList адаптерами и возвращаем его
    ArrayList<SimpleAdapter> returnAdapter = new ArrayList<SimpleAdapter>();
    returnAdapter.add(sa_inspiration);
    returnAdapter.add(sa_skills);
    returnAdapter.add(sa_popularity);
    returnAdapter.add(sa_performances);
    return returnAdapter;
}
}
```

**Game.java**

```
ArrayList<SimpleAdapter> alsa = new ArrayList<SimpleAdapter>();
alsa = (new ListBuilder()).lv_builder();
lv1.setAdapter(alsa[0]);
lv2.setAdapter(alsa[1]);
lv3.setAdapter(alsa[2]);
lv4.setAdapter(alsa[3]);
```

Что не так? Вот лог:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference`

Comment: а на какую строку кода указывает ошибка?

Comment: 957 строчка, `alsa = (new ListBuilder()).lv_builder();`

Comment: по-моему, вы ошибаетесь: строка кода, на которую указывает ошибка, должна вызывать метод getApplicationContext()...

Comment: покажите полную версию кода вашего класса `ListBuilder`

Comment: Дополнил вопрос кодом `ListBuilder`. Но я уже почти сам решил проблему. Если убрать наследование класса от `Activity` и заменить метод на более простой, то все работает. Я с радостью возвращаю метод `lv_builder()` и смотрю, что теперь из-за того, что нет `Activity`, методы `getResources()` стали ошибками. Как мне быть-то? Почему не вызывается метод из класса, наследующего `Activity`? Как это устранить? Или, может, есть другие способы?

Comment: С конструктором класса, я думаю, можно поработать, отдавая ему контекст.

Comment: Нужно сразу сказать, что за такой код, на любой работе с этим связанной, вас бы не задумываясь выгнали. Здесь нарушены все принципы разработки

Comment: @pavlofff, я самоучка :)  и как бы новичок) а какие советы вы бы дали? Напишите пожалуйста как можно улучшить код? Наверное метод. `getResources()` нужно вызвать один раз `Resources res = getResources();` а потом `res.getStringArray`? Или не только?

Comment: Наследоваться от активити, чтобы только получить контекст самое неудачное решение, которое можно было придумать и от него нужно непременно отказаться и никогда больше никому не говорить, что делали так. Активити - контроллер виджетов на экране, тяжелый и "дорогой" класс, глубоко интегрированный в систему, если вы думаете, что написали `extends Activity` и на этом все закончилось, то вы очень глубоко заблуждаетесь.  И это только первая сточка ...

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо. Я уже держу все в одном классе, поплясал с бубном вокруг AIDE, все нормально

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Класс Game унаследован от `Activity`?
По хорошему вам нужно создать конструктор `ListBuilder(Context context)` и переменную `private Context mContext;`

```
public class ListBuilder {
    private Context mContext;
    String[] from = {"todo", "inspiration", "popularity", "money", "guitar", "vocals", "charisma"};
    int[] to = {R.id.todo, R.id.inspiration, R.id.popularity, R.id.money, R.id.guitar, R.id.vocals, R.id.charisma};

    public ListBuilder(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<SimpleAdapter> lv_builder(){

        //заполняем массивы из ресурсов (с использованием переданного контекста приложения)
        if(mContext != null){
            String[] inspiration_todo = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.inspiration_todo);
        }
    }
}
```

Если Game не связан с `Activity`, можно завести вспомогательный класс со статичными данными, в который и класть Context для дальнейшего использования